# Disable/Change Timestamp of ApplicationContext of Spring Boot from console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timestamp, applicationcontext

Everytime we start our Spring Boot Application, Spring Boot prints the line below:

> 2017-07-20 00:43:53.605 INFO 3857 --- [ main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@65d83111: startup date [Thu Jul 20 00:43:53 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy.

I would like to change the timestamp format of the above line i.e. `[Thu Jul 20 00:43:53 UTC 2017]`. If not at least disable from printing the timestamp. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward answer will be, add following line to the `application.properties` file located at `my_awesome_project/src/resources` .

`logging.pattern.console= %-5level %logger - %msg%n`

For exploring more about custom logging, refer below link:

[Spring boot logging using properties config](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-application-properties/)

Answer (score -1):

There's two properties you can set, one for a file, one for console.

`logging.pattern.console`

`logging.pattern.file`

Set these within the application.properties file to override the default.