# How to disable time and date info in console logs Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, console

[image]

How to disable time and date for console logs ? Is there any way ? Screen is not wide enough and this takes unnecessary place . Really annoys me

Comment: Check out following [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75172143/21043233)...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `spring-boot`, then by default it is using `logback` as it's logging mechanism. My suggestion is for you to do changes via `logback.xml` file in-order to change the log pattern.

It is a easy fix and create `logback.xml` file in your project's resources directory.
I will mention below a sample `xml` for that. You can use my example and it will solve your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Appender for logging within the console -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <!-- Pattern of the console logging -->
 
            <!-- %d - Date and time -->
            <!-- %thread - Thread name -->
            <!-- %level - Log level (%p also works) -->
            <!-- %logger - Logger name -->
            <!-- %msg - Log message (%m also works) -->
            <!-- %n - Line separator -->
 
            <!-- %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} - Custom Date/Time format -->
            <!-- %-5level - Left justification flag - Use spaces for right padding if characters < 5 -->
            <!-- %logger{36} - Abbreviate -->
 
            <!-- [Date and time] [Thread] LoggingLevel : LoggerName - Logging message -->
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level: %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
 
    <!-- Logging levels are, in order of precedence -> TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN and ERROR -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
 
</configuration>
```

Above `logback.xml` contains more comments for better understanding. You can control the pattern of your logs as you wish via modifying the `<pattern>`.

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: I guess it'll work but it is complex and long, especially for junior like me. Isn't there any properties in application.properties to add to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Xaxage, you can change the application logging level via application properties but using the above XML is the easiest and simplest approach for doing changes to the log pattern.